# .htaccess rewrite all characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What pattern do I need to rewrite all characters in the requested URL? I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?engine=$1&q=$2 [NC,L]
```

But the dots `.` are not getting recognized.

Answer (score 11):

(.*) will match all characters. That's all you need.

Comment: but im getting some troubles with the images on the site, they are not appearing if I put the ruke like: ^([a-z\-_0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?engine=$1&q=$2any clue?

Answer (score 2):

To match *everything* you can just use: `^(.+)/(.+)/?$` (with optional trailing slash)

If you want to stick with the existing format using character classes, you have a couple of problems here. Inside character sets/classes, you should always put hyphens at the end for a valid regex. You've also omitted uppercase characters.  So to match a basic alphanumeric, underscore and hyphen you want:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]
```

or, using character escapes:

```
[\w\d_-]
```

Your second bracket set is currently specifically excluding period and slash, matching all others.

If your application data is well-defined you may want to go with defined character classes, and 404 on all other data. If you want the blanket redirect, then the following should fix you up:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?engine=$1&q=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: it is working (both answers (*) and yours @tomwalsham but why are the images disappearing? as the path where not ok or re-chaged, any clues?

Comment: You will want to use the <base href='http://example.org/'> tag to reset all relative references on the site to base, as with mod_rewrite they are interpreted as being executed in subfolders.

Comment: mmm is not working, are u sure it is a problem of the php file and not of the .htaccess?

Comment: If the page is loading fine, but the images are broken, this is either a problem of the relative paths of the images being broken by the mod_rewrite, or that you're also rewriting the image paths to go to the index.php   In Firefox you can RightClick->View Image to see if you're loading your main file. Alternatively, you will need to use a less broad regex, or a rewritecond.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/` before the RewriteRule line may help you (assuming your images are all contained within /images/

Comment: aww nothing! how could I add the dots on the last section ([^/.]+) for my rule ^([a-z\-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?engine=$1&q=$2 if I take out the /. I have the same problem with the src's

Answer (score 0):

Thats for sure, because images and even favicon.ico will be 'rewritten' to your index.php instead, try these rules for exception of 'static' files and directories.. This code will read anything that exists for real, if not it will redirect it to your index.php for processing:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(^.*)\.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule     .               /index.php              [L]
```

One more way to exclude 'certain' files or directories is using a line like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
```